# fail to make anaconda spyder my default python platform

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am new to Python. I used Windows 7 System. I installed Python 2.7. Then I installed Anaconda. When I installed Anaconda, I selected the following.

[image]

Therefore, I think it Anaconda should be regarded as my default Python platform. However, when I checked cmd. The result is as following.
[image]

It seems that the default Python platform is still not Anaconda. HoW to change default Python platform to Anaconda Spyder? I tried to unload Anaconda and re-install it again, but it doesn't help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: search "environment variables" in windows search,  click on anything that says "edit system environment variables" or something like that, edit system variables and edit "Path" variable to remove "C:\Python27\" from the list. sorry cant help you wih screenshots, but its easy enough. Google "edit environment variables".

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It helped me a lot.